# Add fuzzy completion to custom helm source

Tags: helm, helm-sources, fuzzy-matching

I am experimenting with custom `helm` sources, but I cannot figure out how to get fuzzy completion to work with it. Here is an example:

```
(defun my-helm-test()
  (interactive)
  (let ((some-helm-source
         '((name . "my helm test")
           (candidates . ("abc xyz" "age hgi" "afg ggg" "ahh iii"))
           (fuzzy-match . t)
           (action . (lambda (candidate)
                    (message-box "%s" candidate))))))
         (helm :sources some-helm-source)))
```

When I type `a` followed by `SPACE` followed by `x` in the helm window, I was hoping to be able to select the `"abc xyz"` candidate. Instead, once I type `SPACE` no candidates are left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `helm` did not recognize the `fuzzy-match` attribute in my source for some reason. I solved this by using `helm-build-sync-source` instead of creating a custom source:

```
(defun my-helm-test()
  (interactive)
  (helm :sources
        (helm-build-sync-source "my helm test"
          :candidates '("abc xyz" "age hgi" "afg ggg" "ahh iii")
          :action (lambda (candidate)
                      (message-box "%s" candidate)))))
```

Now fuzzy matching works as expected.